# Understanding Collision Detection in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am playing with d3.js and collision detection, I am not sure how to implement it. I have a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtriangle/3wgfrrnv/

simple code:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr("width", 960)
        .attr("height", 480);

var circleContainer = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var originX = 100 * (1 + 2.5 * Math.random()),
    originY = 80 * (1 + 2.5 * Math.random());

circleContainer[i] = svg.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'circle-' + i)
        .attr('cx', originX)
        .attr('cy', originY)
        .attr('originX', originX)
        .attr('originY', originY)
        .attr('r', 20)
        .attr('fill','red');
}

transition();

function transition() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    circleContainer[i].transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('cx',  circleContainer[i].attr('originX') * (1 + Math.random()/10))
        .attr('cy',  circleContainer[i].attr('originY') * (1 + Math.random()/10))
        .each("end", transition)
        .ease("linear");
  }

}
```

that is just circle svg objects randomly floating. Would really appreciate insight into the mechanics of collision detection. As always, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to detect collision or an algorithm which avoids collision, if later then you can check for force directed d3 example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 (They don't overlap)

Comment: Have you seen this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)?  It's a force layout but the `collide` function is a pretty simplistic implementation of circle-circle collision.

Comment: @Cyril I am trying to understand an algorithm to detect collision.